# How to run the same e2e tests on different enviroments in playwright

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

I have a set of e2e tests.
We have a test enviroment: test.mypage.com
And we also have a UAT enviroment: uat.mypage.com
I want to be able to run the same e2e tests on either our test or uat enviroment, depending on the command line i use.

my config file:

```js
import { LaunchOptions } from 'playwright';

const browserOptions: LaunchOptions = {
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 0,
    args: []
};

export const config = {
    browserOptions,
    env: {
        server: 'test'
    }
};
```

my step file:

```js
Given(/^i go to login page$/, async function () {
    await PW.page.goto(`https://${config.env.server}.mypage.com/`);
});
```

the command line I use to run my tests:

```
npx cucumber-js
```

So I assume the solution would be something like

```
npx cucumber-js --server "uat"
```

but either my syntax is wrong or I'm missing something. When I run the script above, I get an error: `unknown option: '--server'`.

I tried

```
npx cucumber-js `$env:server="uat"
```

which didn't throw any errors but the environment remained `test.mypage.com`.

So how can I change the environment from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [baseurl](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-base-url) test option for this.

In your config file, add the baseurl:

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: `https://${config.env.server}.mypage.com/`,
  },
};
export default config;
```

So now your test should look like this:

```js
Given(/^i go to login page$/, async function () {
    await PW.page.goto('/');
});
```

Now from CLI, you can run with a different baseurl like this:

```js
URL=https://playwright.dev npx playwright test
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand, if my config file looks like yours, the baseURL: `https://${config.env.server}.mypage.com/`, part has an error: Block-scoped variable 'config' used before its declaration. 

I probably also should mention that im using Playwright Library, not the test runner, if it makes any difference.

Comment: instead of using the variables, try hardcoding the url, and then try updating the url from cli to check if this works, then we can figure out the variable part.

Comment: i kinda tried to do that, but how do i update the hardcoded url from cli?

Comment: like this `URL=https://playwright.dev npx playwright test`